# c# newb question from "Head Start C# Greyhound Lab"

Tags: c#

i'm new at C #  and i'm creating a racetrack simulator, but i'm currently encountering some issues when i run my code. I have  an array of four Greyhound objects, and if I call Greyhound.Run on my form1.cs and i don't have  a "MessageBox.Show("Distance" + distance)" on my Run method, which shows me how many pixels each greyhound is supposed to move, all of the greyhounds end up moving the same distance. I don't understand why this is happening

```
namespace Race
{
    class Greyhound
    {
        public int StartingPosition;
        public int RacetrackLength;
        public PictureBox MyPictureBox = null;
        public int Location = 0;
        public Random Randomizer;

        public bool Run()
        {
            Point p = MyPictureBox.Location;
            if (p.X + MyPictureBox.Width >= RacetrackLength)
            {
                //TakeStartingPostion();
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                Randomizer = new Random();
                int distance = Randomizer.Next(100);
                MessageBox.Show("Distance is " + distance);
                p.X += distance;
                MyPictureBox.Location = p;
                return false;
            }

        }

        public void TakeStartingPostion()
        {
            Point P = MyPictureBox.Location;
            P.X = StartingPosition;
            MyPictureBox.Location = P;
        }
    }
}


namespace Race
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Guy[] guys = new Guy[3];
        Greyhound[] hounds = new Greyhound[4];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            hounds[0] = new Greyhound()
            { 
                StartingPosition = 12,
                MyPictureBox = GreyHound1,
                RacetrackLength = 636
            };

            hounds[1] = new Greyhound()
            { 
                StartingPosition = 12,
                MyPictureBox = GreyHound2,
                RacetrackLength = 636
            };

            hounds[2] = new Greyhound()
            { 
                StartingPosition = 12,
                MyPictureBox = GreyHound3,
                RacetrackLength = 636
            };

            hounds[3] = new Greyhound()
            { 
                StartingPosition = 12,
                MyPictureBox = GreyHound4,
                RacetrackLength = 636
            };
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hounds.Length; i++)
            {

                 hounds[i].Run();
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `new Random()` each time the `Run()` method hits the `else` block. The default `Random` constructor initializes the pseudorandom number generator based on the current time. When there's no interruption, all 4 method run at "the same time", so they spit out the same random numbers. To fix this, either create only a single `Random`, or else use a different seed for each one (by using the `Random` constructor that takes a seed as a parameter.)

Something like this would work:

```
public class Greyhound
{
    public static Random randomizer = new Random();

    // ... In the run method ...
    int distance = Greyhound.randomizer.Next(100);

}
```

**Update**: As Groo points out, if you were actually calling `Next()` from multiple threads, the code I've shown isn't thread-safe. While that's not the case with your code, it's a good idea to be aware of issues like this earlier rather than later. The general solution to this (potential) problem is to surround the call to `Next()` with a `lock`, like so:

```
// ... After the declaration of randomizer ...
private static object randomLock = new object();

// ... New Next() call...
lock (randomLock)
    Greyhound.randomizer.Next(100);
```

Comment: @Alfonso, @dlev: This example is [not thread safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx). You should lock around each call to the `Next` method. That's why it's simpler to create your own static Random class which will do the locking by itself.

Comment: @Groo I'm aware, but it's irrelevant that it's not threadsafe: the OP is using only a single thread (since the initial code snippet ran them all from a for loop, and the current snippet runs them based on button clicks, which will all be run from the UI thread.) You're of course correct in general, though; I'll add an update to mention the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably call the `Run` methods of all of your objects quickly in succession, each instance of the `Random` class gets instantiated [with the same seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx#Y305), returning the same pseudo-random number.

You can solve this problem by creating a static random class which will have a single (Singleton) `Random` instance, making sure that each of your callers gets the next number in succession.

With some locking for thread safety, it would look something like:

```
 public class StaticRandom 
 {
      private static readonly Random _r = new Random();
      private static object _lock = new object();

      public static int Next(int max)
      {
           lock (_lock)
               return _r.Next(max);
      }
 }
```

And then use it without instantiating it:

```
 // no need for the "Randomizer" field anymore
 int distance = StaticRandom.Next(100);
```

Jon Skeet has the full implementation in his miscutil library, along with some [usage info](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/staticrandom.html).